# Is it possible with Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible with Autodesk Forge?

1. Upload the DWG file and view it on the web. Maybe I can use Forge's viwer API. Is that right?
2. And the web has a button. Can I move the focus to a specific object when I click that button? Using Javascript.
   (I will assign ID values to objects while working in Autodesk CAD.)
3. Similar to Question 2. Can I change the color of a specific object using JavaScript?

I'm not good at English. Please politely understand.
Help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you actually tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Upload the DWG file and view it on the web. Maybe I can use Forge's viwer API. Is that right?

Yes follow the tutorial [here](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/)

> And the web has a button. Can I move the focus to a specific object when I click that button? Using Javascript.

Try `viewer.isolate(dbid)` or `viewer.fitToView(dbid)`

> Can I change the color of a specific object using JavaScript?

Try `viewer.setThemingColor`

You can find doc/usage details for these methods on our official website

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Do I have to use the 'Model Derivative API' to upload DWG files? Do I have to pay to use this API?

Comment: Yes use the Model Derivative service and see pricing [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing)

Comment: Thank you for answer.

You said you were using "dbid".
How can I assign ID values to objects in Auto CAD?