# How to use "dbid" in autodeks forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to make a function that click a button in javascript to go to a specific location.

I want to use "viewer.isolate (dbid) or viewer.fitToView (dbid)".
([Is it possible with Autodesk Forge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453559/is-it-possible-with-autodesk-forge/59455833?noredirect=1#comment105107343_59455833))

How do I specify "dbid" when creating a dwg file with autodesk cad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *dbId* is defined when Forge translates your design files (whether it's AutoCAD, Inventor, SolidWorks, Revit, etc.) for the viewer, so you cannot really specify *dbIds* in the CAD application. You can however use the viewer APIs to [search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#search-text-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback-attributenames) for objects with specific properties, for example, with a specific AutoCAD handle or with a specific Revit ID, and obtain the *dbId* that way.

Once you have a *dbId* of an object you're interested in, you can use any of the viewer APIs to select it, hide it, navigate to it, etc.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

Is it possible to move the screen to a specific element using search api?

Comment: Yes, you can use `viewer.search(...)` to find the dbId of your object, and then call `viewer.fitToView(dbid)` to move the camera to it.